# What is the blue section of a partition in Disk Utility?

Tags: disk-utility

What is the blue section at the top of this image (above Macintosh hard drive partition)? Is it another partition, it only seems to exist on this partition when I create a new one. Where do I find the EFI boot partition?

[image]

Thanks :-)

Comment: Just a guess - the blue region indicates how much space is used. So you can't make the partition any smaller than the blue region or else you won't have enough space for existing directories and files.

Comment: Disk Utility doesn't show me a blue region but I think this is because I am using FileVault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The blue shaded area in the image provided is part of the Macintosh HD volume.

The blue shading denotes the used space on a volume.

The EFI boot system cannot be viewed or modified with any Apple-supplied GUI tool.

Comment: how do I mount it (EFI system partition) with bash?

Comment: @rubixibuc - Out of curiosity, why do you want to?

Comment: http://themacadmin.com/?p=603